# deleted friend declaration declares a non-template function

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to delete a specific overloaded friend function in a class.

The below code compiles, and works in the way intended.
However, I get the following warning (g++, c++11,14,17):
edit: Warning is present using gcc9.3 and older, but not for gcc10

```
warning: friend declaration 'bool operator==(const MyType<BaseT>&, const BaseT&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
    6 |   friend bool operator==(const MyType<BaseT> &lhs, const BaseT &rhs) = delete;
      |                                                                        ^~~~~~
new.cpp:6:72: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
```

Can someone shed light on the warning? Why does it apply for the deleted function, but not the implemented one?

```
template <typename BaseT> struct MyType {
  BaseT v;
  explicit  MyType(BaseT tv) : v(tv) {}
  explicit  operator BaseT() const { return v; }

  friend bool operator==(const MyType<BaseT> &lhs, const BaseT &rhs) = delete;
  friend bool operator==(const MyType<BaseT> &lhs, const BaseT &&rhs) {
    return lhs.v == rhs;
  }
};

int main(){
    MyType<int> a{3};
    int b{3};
    // a==b; //Fails to compile: good. Do not allow comparisons between different types
    a==3;    //Compiles fine: good. Allow literal comparison, without implicit constructor
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would you want to declare a deleted function as a `friend` anyway?   Declaring something as a `friend` allows it (if defined) to access private members of a class.   Deleting it means it should not be called, so there is no need to define it, let alone for that definition to access private members.

Comment: @Peter tbh, the answer is laziness.. If I declare it as a free function, I have to specify the template parameters. In the real code, there are several.
If I don't define it, then the overload will "fall through", and the a==b case would compile, which is not what I want.

Comment: @Peter Also - it is desirable to have the allowed and deleted functions declared right next to each other, inside the class body. If one is declared inside, and the other outside, it may be confusing later when looking for the definitions

Comment: @Const Please note that the asker mentioned older versions of g++: https://godbolt.org/z/vDkD4n . Older versions of clang++ reject this code with a different error: https://godbolt.org/z/miY6_A